# jmeter 3.3 CSV example throws stackoverflow exception

Tags: jmeter, stack-overflow

I download JMeter 3.3 and opened the example CSVSample.jmx in examples folder and executed, I get the below Stackoverflow exception 
Test Plan:
[image: 1]

```
017-09-24 16:38:09,452 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.AbstractCallSiteDescriptor.hashCode(AbstractCallSiteDescriptor.java:142) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornCallSiteDescriptor.get(NashornCallSiteDescriptor.java:167) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornCallSiteDescriptor.get(NashornCallSiteDescriptor.java:158) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.LinkerCallSite.newLinkerCallSite(LinkerCallSite.java:114) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.Bootstrap.bootstrap(Bootstrap.java:208) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.Bootstrap.createDynamicInvoker(Bootstrap.java:371) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.Bootstrap.createDynamicInvoker(Bootstrap.java:345) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.InvokeByName.<init>(InvokeByName.java:86) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.InvokeByName.<init>(InvokeByName.java:73) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.<init>(Global.java:96) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.newGlobal(Context.java:1111) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$2.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:350) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$2.run(NashornScriptEngine.java:346) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.createNashornGlobal(NashornScriptEngine.java:346) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.createGlobalMirror(NashornScriptEngine.java:340) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.createBindings(NashornScriptEngine.java:170) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController$NashornJsEngine.evaluate(IfController.java:123) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.evaluateCondition(IfController.java:185) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.next(IfController.java:239) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:219) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:173) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.next(WhileController.java:106) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.nextIsNull(WhileController.java:82) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:168) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.next(WhileController.java:106) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:222) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:173) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.WhileController.next(WhileController.java:106) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) condition uses a function **__jexl** that has been removed:

> ${__jexl("${ACTION}" != "")}

Should be:

> ${[__jexl3](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3)("${ACTION}" != "")}

Fixed today in jmeter code:

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1809530